# Apache2 Virtualhost going to default DocRoot

Tags: html, redirect, apache2, virtualhost

I am having trouble setting up virtual hosts on my ubuntu server 12, apache2. When I attempt to go to stemitest.com apache directs to the `DocumentRoot` in `000-default.conf` (`/var/www/`). What am I doing wrong?

```
cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/
```

```
cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/stemitest.com.conf 


<virtualhost *:80>

  ServerAdmin donotreply@epbfi.com
  ServerName  www.stemitest.com
  ServerAlias stemitest.com


  DirectoryIndex index.html
  DocumentRoot /var/www/stemitest.com


  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/apachelogs/error.log
  CustomLog /var/apachelogs/access.log combined

</virtualhost>

cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    ...
    Include /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    <ifmodule mod_ssl.c>
        NameVirtualHost *:443
    </ifmodule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem, sort of.  Apache wasn't following the simlink in sites-enabled.  Everything works after I copy my stemitest.com.conf to sites-enabled.  Seems like a hack, though.  Anyone have any idea why apache has this behavior?